# Not enough server storage is available to process this command - RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore, windows-server

First a little description of the system that I'm seeing the problem on:

My firm has a regularly scheduled restoration of a database from backups of another, I won't go into the business reasons for this.

The database being restored is on an instance of SQL Server 2014 with SP2-CU1 updates which is running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM.

The drive on which the mdf/ndf/ldf files are, has 1.19TB free space, and the database occupies some 863GB. The .bak files themselves are held There are also some other database files on this drive leaving 244GB free, which I assume is enough for it to do a restore without any issue related to insufficient working space.

Over the weekend we do a restoration from a full backup, and every other day is from a differential. We sometimes see the restoration fail multiple times in a row, at present I've had some 8 or 9 consecutive failed attempts since Monday. This usually occurs when restoring from the full backup which leads me to believe that it's a performance issue with SQL Server when handling large databases, or it might be something funny with the VMs?

The error I am seeing when it fails is below. This can occur at seemingly any point during the restoration, for instance the last attempt it got up to 76% complete on restoring the full backup before keeling over.

```
Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Read on "\\VM\Backups\TheDatabase.bak" failed: 1130(Not enough server storage is available to process this command.)
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
Msg 4319, Level 16, State 5, Line 3
A previous restore operation was interrupted and did not complete processing on file 'TheDatabase'. Either restore the backup set that was interrupted or restart the restore sequence.
Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

There is a project to do partitioning so we need only backup and restore the hot portion of the DB, which should hopefully resolve this, but I am looking for anything in the interim which could potentially reduce the occurences of this or stop this from happening entirely. Let me know if more info is needed to diagnose this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is misleading you, it's not talking about disk storage on the machine where you are restoring.

The windows error message states:

> 1130(Not enough **server storage** is available to process this command.)

When you check that error message you will notice that it's not an error during the restore operation but rather during the **file copy** operation over the network as [documented here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304101)

> The two causes of this problem are related. The more frequent cause is listed first:
>   More files are open than the memory cache manager can handle. As a result, the cache manager has exhausted the available paged pool memory.
>   The backup program has tried to back up a file whose size is larger than the backup API can access on that version of the operating system. This has the same result (that is, the paged pool is exhausted).
>   Note This second issue is more likely to occur on a Microsoft
>   Windows NT 4.0-based computer.
>
> The resolution for each problem differs depending on whether you
>   experience the problem in Windows Server 2003, in Microsoft Windows
>   2000, or in Windows NT 4.0.

[Or here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/106167)

> When you access shared items on a Windows NT server from a Windows NT
>   client, you may receive the following error message:   Not enough
>   server storage is available to process this command.

So as you say, you likely have enough storage to restore the database but you are running into issues retrieving the file over the network. 
In any case you need to be looking at some SMB issue

Had you been running into disk space problems during the restore the error message would have been:

> 112(There is not enough space on the disk.)

As [@Nic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/11639/nic) correctly pointed out in the comments you should probably try to copy the backup file over using [an unbuffered file copy (use ESEUTIL or XCOPY)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/05/08/slow-large-file-copy-issues/) and restore from there to either solve or at least isolate the issue.

If you still run into issues copying over the file that way I'm not sure that still fits the scope of dba.se.

Comment: Are the causes and related resolutions the same in Windows Server 2012 R2 as you've described for a Windows Server 2003, Microsoft Windows 2000, or Windows NT 4.0 server? I'm a little skeptical of this being the case as we're not using anything quite as old as any of those software.

Comment: The operating system error is the same, what the exact solutions are will depend on your environment, there is plenty to find on google if you search the windows operating system error

Comment: @Nic Copying the .bak files to the local machine and then restoring worked. Many Thanks!

Comment: @TomV Regarding the server, my colleague had tried increasing the paged pool memory on a previous occasion of this issue but saw little improvement, though I will keep in mind to push for other/general improvements to the VM and physical servers none the less. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue just yesterday. Let me explain my scenario.
I would like to restore 10+ dbs from
one physical machine SQL Server 2008R2(Windows Server 2008R2)
to another physical machine 2016(Windows Server 2012R2) for a migration.
**Important point:** Backup files was on the source machine, restore triggered from the the sharing created on source backup disk.(network dependent scenario)
For small dbs(<500GB), It was OK and restore was successful as expected.
But when It came to gigantic sized dbs(>2TB), restore operations unexpectedly started to fail and same error appeared. These results repeated for all my attempts, the only different was "percent complete level" at which restore operation failed.

Someone here also said error message was misleading, it is true. It makes you think like it was related with storage but it is not.
What I've done?

I realized that, source machine(backups located) had running out of memory allocated for OS at one point during restore. This point is where zero memory remained for OS related operations and any attempt will dramatically halt.
So, I decreased the memory allocated for SQL Engine %20.
(memory distribution before operation, %90 SQL- %10 OS )
So that OS had a chance to allocate much more memory for such operations.
This time all attempts were successful for the ones failed before.

Note: As soon as migration finished, I gave the memory back to SQL Engine on source machine.

Note2: Increasing source machine's RAM capacity adding new slots would be other option if applicable.
Throttling memory might not be a good idea for some instances, Should think twice.

The bigger your backup size is, the more physical memory space needed to handle by memory cache manager for your network dependent operations. This is my learning from the experience. You need to monitor available memory allocated for OS during such operations.
Hope it helps you guys!